# Wrong Python date calculation.

Tags: python, r, hadoop

I was trying to compare R's date and the Python's date. Since R is using 1970-01-01 by default for its "delta-day". So I also tried "1970-01-01" for Python's "deltatime".

In R it returns 14975 for 2011-01-01 and 15273 for 2011-10-26.
But Python returns 14975 and 15000.

Below is what I typed in on my Python console. I really don't understand the result. 
Any suggestions? I am using Python 2.6 (the built-in version for Hadoop)

```
>>> (datetime.strptime("2011-01-01", '%Y-%M-%d').date() - datetime.strptime("1970-01-01", '%Y-%M-%d').date()).days
14975
>>> (datetime.strptime("2011-10-26", '%Y-%M-%d').date() - datetime.strptime("1970-01-01", '%Y-%M-%d').date()).days
15000
>>>
```

Comment: `%M` is for minute, not month. Try `%m`.

Comment: I really doubt that people who marked this post as "off-topic" are helping the stackOverflow community. They did not provide any answer at all. They just down voting or 'flagging'. People like me, from other programming language need to know that, for example'm%' and 'M%' are different! If they flagged it as 'duplicated post' and point me to the correct answer, i can understand. 'Off-topic'??? LOL

Comment: Not that I necessarily agree with it, but I think is has more to do with the specific phrase "simple typographical error".

Comment: It is hardly a simple "typo" to mistake Minutes for months (unless you were actually trying to type an 'm', which I doubt..)  Some people on SO are just too trigger happy with the close button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I recommend [python-dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) parser to avoid these annoying trip-ups

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("2011-10-26")
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 26, 0, 0)
```

Comment: `dateutil` might be an overkill if the format is fixed. There is http://strftime.org/ to help look up `strftime()` format codes.